Need for autostart permission to run workmanager?
I cannot find this information online.
I created an app that works as I want. However, I create a workmanager class and I need to ask for autostart permission for my doWork() method to work:
public class CheckpointWorker extends Worker {

    private static final String TAG = "CheckpointWorker";
    //private int notificationId = 1;

    public CheckpointWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(appContext, workerParams);
    }

@NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        // my code
    }
}

So, if I grant autostart permission, everything works great. If I don't grant it, the workmanager seems not to work. I was just wondering if this is the expected behavior, because from what I understood, workmanager should not need autostart permission. I am working with Android 10 on a Xiomi Redmi Note 8T

What is "autostart permission"? Is this something specific to Xiaomi devices? Or are you referring to the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission.
